# add custome dependency to spark

Tags: apache-spark, config, log4j2

I want to add `<JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json" charset="UTF-8"/>` to `log4j2.xml` for spark configuration.

but I don't have `JsonTemplateLayout` dependency. how can I add this dependency to spark?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that both log4j-core and log4j-json modules are included in your project. To use log4j with Apache Spark, you need to add the following dependencies to your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-json</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the version numbers above are the latest version of log4j, you may need to adjust the version numbers appropriately depending on the version of log4j you are using.

Comment: `JsonTemplateLayout` is not it `log4j-json` but [`log4j-layout-template-json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-layout-template-json). BTW: please don't include in your answers versions with known vulnerabilities (`log4j-core` less than `2.17.1`).